# Creating a new object by giving a handle to its definition

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

In [this Udacity video on game development](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs255/l-52850041/e-52156969/m-52630843), the instructor mentions that Javascript allows us to create an object by giving a handle to its definition. Then, it says that to allow this "an overloaded object definition will update a hash table with a pointer to its class definition".

I quite know what a hash table, a pointer, an overloaded method, and the factory pattern are, but I cannot make sense of this mysterious statement, or of the rest of the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Hash table" is just a fancier way of saying "ordinary Javascript object". What the instructor means by "handle to its definition" is just another way of saying "the function that acts as a constructor for the class".

Ultimately, what he means by the statement you mentioned:

> each overloaded entity definition will update a hash table with a pointer to its class definition

is the following:

- All "subclasses" of Entity will register their constructor function in a single shared hashmap/object using the key which is the `type` value.
- This allows you to get the constructor function (in other words, the function to call `new` on, which will return an instance of that entity) for any type by accessing `gGameEngine.factory[type]`.

This is nice, because whenever a programmer adds a new type of entity, so long as they remember to add a new entry to that `gGameEngine.factory` object with the correct key, then that object will contain everything you need to construct any type of supported object.

So the code that iterates over the JSON structure generated by the level editor can create an instance of any type the same way, using something like:

```
var typeConstructor = gGameEngine.factory(tileSpec.type),
    instance;

if (typeConstructor) {
    instance = new(typeConstructor)(tileSpec /* or whatever params */);
}
```

This is similar to the code visible at around the 1 minute mark of the video you linked to.

Make sense now?

Comment: Almost. So, is `new(typeConstructor)` equivalent to `new typeConstructor`? Does this syntax has a name? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: @Federico I believe they are equivalent, yes. It's just adding parentheses to arguably make it clearer what is happening, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think all he's saying is that you can map references to functions / objects / variables inside another object. He's using one type of [property accessor syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), but I think he's overcomplicating things by using language like 'handle' and 'hash table'.

```
var someClass = function () {
  // stuff
}

var containingObject = {};
containingObject["someClass"] = someClass;
// same thing as
containingObject.someClass = someClass;
```

Then you can instantiate the class by calling the `containingObject` property.

```
var classInstance = new containingObject["someClass"]()
// or
var classInstance = new containingObject.someClass()
```